# How do I perform exponentiation in Apex?

Tags: apex, math

I am trying to perform this calculation in apex. How do I use the exponential operator in apex? For example, the below operation:

```
4000*(0.01/(1-(1+0.01)^(-12)))
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [the `Math` class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_math.htm), which contains methods for mathematic operations like exponentiation (`pow()`).